# Is it possible to spot a unique identifier for objects while debugging in .net?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013

I'm chasing a bug right now and I'm in a sort of a loop where the program goes through the same function many times. What I need to find out is whether or not one of the function arguments is the exact same object as one of the ones that entered the function before, afaik there is no easy way to tell since the content of the object is exactly the same but it could be a copy.

In c++ for example, I can just look at the pointer address of the object and see whether its different or not but no such luck in .net.

Is there something I can turn on, some table column I can unhide or a function I can execute during debug runtime that will give me an unique identifier tied to that object instance like a memory address?

Comment: Visual Studio has the 'Make Object ID' feature that might help you out. Check out 'https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/03/04/make-object-id/' and see if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the object's result of the `GetHashCode` function. If this isn't precise enough for you, you can implement it yourself by inheriting from `IEqualityComparer` and implementing a sufficiently unique method of combining your object's state into a unique identifier. ReSharper has code generation tools for this available throught the alt+insert shortcut.

If you don't have ReSharper available, here is what it's typical implementation does:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int result = (PropertyOne != null ? PropertyOne.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (PropertyTwo != null ? PropertyTwo.GetHashCode() : 0));
            result = (result * 397) ^ (PropertyThree != null ? PropertyThree.GetHashCode() : 0));
            //... etc
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A crude, but simple, way is to add a static integer next id to your class of interest and use this to initialize an object id.

e.g:

```
    class MyClass
    {
      static int MyNextId = 0;
      private int _intanceId;

      public MyClass()
      {
        _instanceId = ++MyNextId;
      }
}
```